# Close Jira Ticket Using Ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am getting the following error when trying to close a JIRA ticket.

```
 - name: Close the issue
      jira: uri={{serverURI}} username={{userName}} password={{password}} issue={{issue.meta.key}} operation=transition  status="resolved"
      tags: close
```

**Error :-**

> TASK [Close the issue]
>   ********************************************************* fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg":
>   "Failed find valid transition for 'Done'"}

How could I solve this issue.

Comment: It's a Jira project configuration issue, you cannot put the issue into state 'Done' from it's current state as the workflow does not allow for it.

Comment: In Jira workflow rules you cannot put the issue into state 'Done' from it's current state as the workflow does not allow for it.

Comment: How could I get the flow to incorporate the same to close the ticket.

Comment: @SPM Is it resolved?

Comment: @Techiee, No, not yet :(

Answer (score 0):

> msg": "Failed find valid transition for 'Done'
>    saying it is unable to find the transition id for the status value "resolved"

Check if resolved defined in the url http://:/rest/api/latest/issue/{issuekey}/transitions

for more info : https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/107630/jira-how-to-change-issue-status-via-rest

Answer (score 0):

Funny enough, **Failed find valid transition**, did me when username of jira Ansible task had no project permissions for transitions.  Be sure to view rest/api/2/issue/{{issue}}/transitions with the same credentials as the tasks